# How to extract multivalue fields from db2 database onto a relational database

Tags: database, db2, extract, talend, multivalue

l need help extracting multivalue fields which are in xml format from db2  for storage into sql server relational database. l tried using Talend Studio for extracting but the multivalue fields cant be extracted as they have data type object which cannot be converted to a  string. How best can l achieve this.

[image]

There are fields like BALANCE_16 and other numbered fields which have multi-values which are not reflected on other fields. How do l solve this?

Comment: This depends on the form you want to get it in. For example, the [XMLSERIALIZE](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-xmlserialize) (BALANCE_16 AS VARCHAR (1000)) function call could be used to get a string representation of an XML expression.

Comment: If BALANCE_16 is in XML format, you can use ```tExtractXMLFields```component to read XML and extract informations into string format. Or you can convert XML into String with ```tConvert```and then apply Regex with ```tJavaRow``` or ``SplitRow```. Can you give more examples for input data and output data?